# Does this SOAP Fault mean what I think it means?

Tags: php, web-services, soap

So, I'm working on integrating Fedex's Address Validation into a site I'm working on. Fedex web services are SOAP-based, so we're in the magical land of WSDLs here. I'm not fluent with web services yet, so bear with me.

One can only consume the Address Validation service at a production level; I've got my production credentials situated, and a production URL in the port section of my WSDL.

In testing the service integration, I'm receiving this provocative message:

Fault
Code:VersionMismatch
String:Wrong Version

Fedex support thus far seems unable to answer this, so I'm gonna ask it here: why am I getting this fault? Am I right in suspecting that perhaps the SOAP version on our server is outdated, and, if so, is there any workaround anyone knows for this?

Comment: The fault code is a bit sparse - which SoapClient are you using?

Comment: Henrik--started off using PHP's native SOAP methods, switched to using NuSOAP, because, well, gives me better debugging info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common reason for this error seems to be a wrong namespace used for the envelope. See http://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-part1/#faultcodes and http://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-part1/#vmfault

Answer (score 2):

There are several versions of both WSDL and SOAP, and PHP seems to have [issues](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48013) with at least [WSDL 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl20/).

Check the header of the WSDL file to verify what FedEx wants (they might provide several web services for different versions) and check with a sniffer what your script actually sends.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you aren't getting a SOAP envelope that's valid and recognised by the client library. In other words, the XML returned by the server that normally looks like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        ...
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

... looks like something else.

Among other reasons, that can happen if the server is crashing badly and sending a random error page, or if the end-point URL is not a SOAP server at all.