# Using PHP SOAP client in non-WSDL mode

Tags: php, web-services, soap, yii

I am working on an api for a client. I have received the following information:

```
API Url: http://xyz-crm.example/WebAPI/Custom/project_name/XML/

Username: foobar
password: spameggs
```

I need to configure the PHP SOAP client for the same in non-WSDL mode. I have written the following but it does not seem to work:

```
$wsdl    = null;
$options = array(
    'uri'      => 'http://xyz-crm.example/WebAPI/Custom/project_name/XML/',
    'location' => 'http://xyz-crm.exmaple.com/WebAPI/Custom/project_name/XML/',
    'login'    => 'foobar',
    'password' => 'spameggs'
);
$client  = new SoapCLient($wsdl, $options);
```

I just want to make a successful ping to the api at first. See if things are working fine. What am I doing wrong here?

**Update 1**

I made the following changes:

```
$wsdl    = null;
$options = array(
    'uri'          => "http://xyz-crm.example/WebAPI/Custom/project_name/XML/",
    'location'     => "http://xyz-crm.example/",
    'Username'     => "foobar",
    'Password'     => "spameggs",
    'soap_version' => '1.2'
);
$client  = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
$client  = $client->getListings();
```

I get the error: `looks like we got no XML document`

> [Edit by me, hakre: This update was done as feedback to [answer #1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19653863/367456). It changes the *location* option using a shortened URL (reason not given by OP) and it adds the *soap_version* option (as suggested in answer #1, but not as constant but as string (containing an invalid value), so there should be no wonder this creates an error, a correct *option* value is given in answer #1 (the `SOAP_1_1` constant) and by intention, the correct value would be the `SOAP_1_2` constant for this example). Error message as commented by OP was *"SOAP Fault: Wrong version."*]

**Update 2**

I tried the following but it still fails:

```
$listing = $client->getListings(); 
$request = $client->__getLastRequest();
```

The execution stops at the first line itself without ever going to the second one.

> [Edit by me, hakre: As review has shown wrong configuration options in *Update 1* already which are not addressed in *Update 2* it would be a miracle if it still wouldn't fail. The execution stops because an [**Exception**](http://php.net/exceptions) is thrown and no error/exception handling is done]

Comment: Do you get any error message (is error reporting switched on?)?

Comment: SOAP Fault: Wrong version. That's the error I get. I am sort of confused by the api uri as well. On the net I see examples with .asmx as the format of the uri or location. This is the first time I am working with SOAP.

Answer (score 2):

Die URI or file ending does not matter, it could even be `.jpg`, there is no default.

Have a look at similiar questions: [Does this SOAP Fault mean what I think it means?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720180/does-this-soap-fault-mean-what-i-think-it-means)

It would be helpful if you put the error message into the question, aswell as the XML output of your request.

try setting the SOAP Version in the array of your `SoapClient` instance to one of the constants (try different ones):

```
new SoapClient($url, array("soap_version" => SOAP_1_1,.......
```

or `SOAP_1_2` ...

To debug the XML try the answer from [Inspect XML created by PHP SoapClient call before/without sending the request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626423/inspect-xml-created-by-php-soapclient-call-before-without-sending-the-request)

The error message of your updated question does not look like it coming from PHP, looks more like an answer from the webservice, means your request is actually working.