# Convert SOAP XML response to PHP object or array

Tags: php, xml, api, soap

I have found this piece of PHP code:

```
<?php

$client = new SoapClient("http://localhost/code/soap.wsdl");

// Soap call with HelloWorld() method
$something =  $client->HelloWorld(array('option1' => 'attribute1'));

// Convert object to array
$array = (array)$something;
```

I just want to know where *soap.wsdl* resides or from where we can download *soap.wsdl* file for PHP.

Comment: The WSDL is typically provided by the service you're trying to access

Comment: @PriyeRanjan: Where did you find that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location of the [WSDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language)-file is going to depend on the SOAP API you're calling. Check their documentation.

The example code you provided of implies they're working locally, and you're hosting the WSDL on your own, local machine.

**Research Edit**

Apparently you can use the [PHP soap client in non-WSDL mode](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php). This is accomplished by passing in `null` as the param instead of the location of the wsdl file.

[Also relevant, is this other SO result on non-WSDL mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19653275/using-php-soap-client-in-non-wsdl-mode.)

Comment: Thank You @Camilo Payan, But it seems the API that i am using does not provide it. Is there any alternative for it.

Comment: WSDL is a language that describes the service (I left a link in the answer). If you learn that language and you learn the SOAP service you're going to consume, you *could* write the WSDL file your own. That would be an alternative approach that is at least technically possible. Depending on your scenario, this most likely is not feasible in your situation. I also kinda guess from the way you ask question you're probably falling into some kind of [x/y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Added some more to my response, @PriyeRanjan let me know if that helps you out at all.